# How to disable registered user account in asp.net membership using checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to disable registered user account in asp.net membership using checkbox ?

Comment: Please add some details. Explain ASP.NET membership.

Comment: I have the following coding to do tha ..but i dont understand where to do that ..

MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(); //to block currently logged in user

MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("username"); //To block a specific user:

user.IsApproved = false; 
Membership.UpdateUser(user);

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but might be helpful to someone. You can edit the database table `aspnet_Membership` directly. Therein, the field 'IsApproved' can be updated with a '0' for the user account.